# Tasks already registered error when dynamically setting dependencies

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

i am trying to dynamically set dependencies and getting task_0 already registered.Below is the code.

```
with dag:

    final_task = DummyOperator(task_id='final')

    for i in range(0, 3):
        d1 = DummyOperator(task_id='tasks_{0}'.format(i))

        for j in range(0, 3):
            d2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task_{0}'.format(i),
                            python_callable=test_callable,
                            provide_context=True)
            d1 >> d2
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Where did you define `d1`?

2) When i = 0, it creates 3 `PythonOperator` with same `task_id`, which is `task_0` inside the for loop for j. That's why you saw that error message.

Comment: when i=0,it it creates 3 PythonOperators with task_0,task_1and task_2 and adds them as dependency to tasks_0 ,I think the issue here is when i=1,again it  creates 3 PythonOperators task_0,task_1and task_2 inside the for loop for j and throwing error since those dependencies are already registered .But this is what i need

Comment: Cool, after you edited your code, it's much clear now. When i = 0, it's gonna loop through j in range (0,3), it will create 3 task_0 for d2 becasues you have task_id='task_{0}'.format(i). I am not sure if you have modified your uploaded code before you uploaded or your original code is like that, but you may want to double check it.